# Action Script: Drawing on video

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash

I was wondering how to draw over a video like this.

http://www.bannerblog.com.au/2009/06/burger_king_sharpie.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that in the example is drawing process over video. As for me It's a 3d model with video background. And you could sync prerecorded states with 3d object transformations (position, rotation, mesh transformations), or create well textured object.

Here for your [tutorial how to draw over the 3D objects](http://blog.onebyonedesign.com/actionscript/drawing-on-stuff-in-away3d-4-0/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Use Adobe After Effects (or any number of other compositing programs).